# Unable to Run Python file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have recently setup Anaconda with python 3.6, and installed tensorflow, networkx, and a github package I am hoping to use. When I run Jupyter Notebook and open a random file, it says "python3" in the upper right hand corner and I am given the standard options to run a cell, create a new cell, etc. However, when I open one of the files from the github package it says "python" in the upper right hand corner and I am only given "file" "edit" "view" and "language" options in the toolbar. I am unsure why it is not giving me an option to simply run the file and since I am new to Python/Anaconda/etc I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Is it a `.py` file, or a `.ipynb` file?

Answer (score 2):

what i ve understood is that you wanna open a python file inside Jupyter Notebook.

However, Jupyter Notebook files have the extension .ipynb which is not the same for python files (.py)

so my answer is : you cant run a python file inside Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a `.py` file from a notebook by importing it just like you would in another `.py` script.